# How to pull all records from a given id in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I stored few data structure in the `mongoDB`.
while storing the objects i let the `mongoDB` to generate the ID for me.

I want to pull all the new recorded / modified ones from a given ID.

By the following i'm getting the last record in the db:

```
dbcursor = (DBCursor) dbcollection.find().sort(new BasicDBObject("_id",-1)).limit(1);
```

how i should modify the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to find the IDs that are greater than x. If that is the case then use the following;

```
dbcursor = (DBCursor) dbcollection.find({ ID : {$gt : 100 }}).sort(new BasicDBObject("_id",-1)).limit(100);
```

This will select top 100 IDs that are greater than 100 and sort it with the same logic as yours.

Comment: how to i use $gt with "$oid" : "54539b44d955585717919df4" ? it is not working... only when the id is int.

Comment: The greater will not work with non integer values. Do you have a TimeStamp? If you have a timestamp, you can locate the ID you want it greater than and search for the timestamp x and greater